# PHP array manipulation

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the code below .  it looks for the case and creates an array of rows and columns. 
  `$pv->results[$row1][1][0]` actually is `$pv->result->[rownumber][coulmnnumber][0]`.
Now this is for only 2 columns as you can see. However  I want an array like 
`$myArr = array(0=>1, 1=>7, 2=>8, 3=>9 )` to be added below for column. What it is doing,  is adding 4 columns (0,1,2,3) into the code below. So now I will have 4 cases instead of 2 cases as I need to more columns. Also the case value will not be 1 and 2, it will be 1, 7, 8 and 9 respectively. How can I do that? Thanks.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($pv->rawData); $i++){ 
SWITCH ($pv->rawData[$i]->my ID){
         CASE '1':
          $row1++;
          $pv->results[$row1][1][0] =  $pv->rawData[$i]->data;

           break;

        CASE '2':
          $row2++;
         $pv->results[$row2][2][0] =  $pv->rawData[$i]->data;

          break;    
}
```

Comment: @user295189: you can use backticks to delineate and format inline code, and indent lines with four spaces for multiline code. Click the orange question mark in the post editor toolbar for more formatting information. Also, your description of what you're trying to accomplish needs quite a bit of clarification. Try including sample input and output data.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand at all what you're after. $pv is an object instance of sorts, but the code above is not valid ($pv->rawData[$i]->my ID), nor do I understand what your cases are supposed to react to (ints, text, what?) As to the last question, case '1': ... break ;case '7': ... break ;case '8': ... break ;case '9': ... break ;

Comment: Wow, did we really have 3 simultaneous edits?

Comment: not sure how else I can explain this better but I will try. All I want is have this kind of out put

Row: 0: Column: 1: ID 1 
Row: 1: Column: 1: ID 1 
Row: 0: Column: 2: ID 2
Row: 1: Column: 2: ID 2 
Row: 2: Column: 2: ID 2 
Row: 3: Column: 2: ID 2 
Row: 0: Column: 3: ID 3
Row: 1: Column: 3: ID 3 

As you can see the Rows and columns change based on the ID. So if the ID is same it just go to next row in the same column. However if id is changed it goes to next column and rows start again

I will add the code in the comment below

Comment: for($i=0;$i<count($pv->rawData); $i++) { 
            $relative=0;
            $relativeTypeID = -1;
            
            
             
              if ($pv->rawData[$i]->relativeTypeID != $relativeTypeID){
          $relativeTypeID = $pv->rawData[$i]->relativeTypeID;
          $iTypeCount++;
          $iColumnHeaders[$iTypeCount] = $pv->rawData[$i]->relation;   
         
              }

Comment: if(!empty($pv->rawData[$i]->description)){
         $pv->results[$i][$iTypeCount][0] =  $pv->rawData[$i]->description;
            $pv->results[$i][$iTypeCount][1] = ' '; 
            $pv->results[$i][$iTypeCount][2] = $pv->results[$i][$iTypeCount][0];
            $pv->results[$i][$iTypeCount][3] = $pv->results[$i][$iTypeCount][0];
            echo  "Row: ".$i.": Column: ".$iTypeCount.": ID".$relativeTypeID."  <br>";                
      }
     }
and I am getting this output from above code
Row: 0: Column: 1: ID1 
Row: 1: Column: 2: ID1 
Row: 2: Column: 3: ID2 
More detailed ..

Comment: Row: 0: Column: 1: ID1 
Row: 1: Column: 2: ID1 
Row: 2: Column: 3: ID2 
Row: 3: Column: 4: ID2 
Row: 4: Column: 5: ID2 
Row: 5: Column: 6: ID2 
Row: 6: Column: 7: ID2 
Row: 7: Column: 8: ID2 
Row: 8: Column: 9: ID2 
Row: 9: Column: 10: ID2 
Row: 10: Column: 11: ID2 
Row: 11: Column: 12: ID2 
Row: 12: Column: 13: ID2 
Row: 15: Column: 16: ID8 
Row: 16: Column: 17: ID8 
Row: 17: Column: 18: ID8 
Row: 18: Column: 19: ID10 
Row: 19: Column: 20: ID10 
Row: 20: Column: 21: ID10 
Row: 22: Column: 23: ID12 
Row: 23: Column: 24: ID17 
Row: 24: Column: 25: ID17 
Row: 25: Column:

Comment: @user295189: clarifications should be made by editing the question. Comments are for things that aren't questions or answers. Comments aren't very readable unless short; everything you just posted scarcely improves matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're looking for this;

```
$idField = 'my ID';
foreach( $pv -> rawData as $data ) $pv -> results[ ++${ 'row' . $data -> $idField } ][ $data -> $idField ][ 0 ] = $data -> data;
```